# Como inibir confirmação "reenvio do formulario"?

Tags: javascript, html, formulário

Tenho uma lista de registros onde faço uma pesquisa (via post) e apos o resultado seleciono um registro através de um select, e vou para outra pagina editar esse registro.
Acontece que quando termino de editar esse registro quero voltar para a pagina anterior `"window.history.go(-1)"`, o navegador exige a confirmação do reenvio do formulário, sei que isso é um padrão do chrome, mas será que tem como voltar sem que ele peça essa confirmação?
Eu preciso sempre usar o method post.

Comment: E pq vc está usando justo o `window.history.go`? Seria melhor mandar para um URL de verdade. O ideal é nunca usar estes métodos, na verdade. O máximo que compensa mexer em histórico, é para manter a navegação via avançar e voltar em páginas com Ajax, por exemplo (e mesmo assim, com um bocado de cuidado). Fora isso, quase sempre é gambiarra.

Comment: que eu saiba nao tem como, a maioria dos navegadores avisam que voce volta para uma pagina com POST, gostava do opera por que nao dava esse aviso. Uma solucao seria ao inves de dar um `window.history.go(-1)` e ir para a pagina de busca novamente, usando os mesmos parametros. ai nao aparece esse aviso.

Comment: Pois é, eu já faço por meio de pesquisa reversa, mas se o history.go funcionasse me poupava um bocado de trabalho, tenho varias paginas nessa situação.

Comment: @Bacco porque usar o `window.history.go(-1)` é gambiarra?

Comment: Tente bolar um jeito de padronizar. Se estiver usando algo server-side, até que não fica muito difícil. É tentador cortar caminho, mas nesse caso acho que compromete coisas essenciais.

Comment: @Marcelo pq antes de mais nada, é um comportamento que depende de uma série de coisas (da maneira que o usuário chegou na página, se foi por link, se abriu em nova aba, se veio de um bookmark) e da implementação do browser. Alem disso, é o tipo de ação que normalmente deve ser voluntária (o usuário controlar, e não a aplicação). Conceitualmente é pra outros usos. Notar que eu disse "quase" sempre. Pode ter situações que se justifique. Mas quase sempre é um engano achar que justifica.

Comment: Esse 'voltar' seria algo simples, no meu caso não iria comprometer nada já que eu somente queria que a pesquisa anterior ficasse selecionada, não importa se houveram atualização de dados. Entendo que numa concorrencia de dados seria um problema, mas não esse o caso.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post

Comment: Marcelo entendo o que você diz, mas no seu caso, o fato é que já comprometeu. Como você percebeu, em usando o voltar (go -1), tem esse desdobramento por ter ocorrido um POST. Dei uma lida por cima no link do @MagicHat, e me parece bem pertinente. O texto não fala de history.go, mas o que fala dos botões de avançar e voltar cai no mesmo. Se você adotar a prática do "não mostre dados no POST, só no GET", vai ter mais tranquilidade (apesar do trabalho extra).

Comment: Dei uma lida na materia sugerida pelo @MagicHat, realmente é um modelo muito bom, eu teria que reprogramar todo meu código, pois faço uso de url amigáveis e oculto o conteudo do link justamente pro cara não guardar o link e ter que vir pela pagina de origem, nesse caso que estou passando um simples GO(-1) ja resolveria meu problema, mas os navegadores não funcionam assim, vou ter que trabalhar um pouco mais, rs, vou fazer uso de sessões pra guardar as pesquisas. Mas valeu o bate papo, foi bem produtivo.