# Sistema de postagem duplicando as postagens - PHP

Tags: php, html

Olá, pessoal! Eu tô desenvolvendo uma rede social e estou na parte de publicações. O Problema é que quando eu vou fazer uma postagem nova e clico em publicar, ele publica a postagem anterior e quando eu atualizo a página é que ele publica a postagem que eu fiz. Como sou novato em PHP ainda, creio eu que tem haver com o cookie do navegador mas não sei como resolver. Enfim, segue o código abaixo:

```html
<?php
    include("header.php");
    
    $pubs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM publicacao ORDER BY id desc");
    
    if (isset($_POST['publish'])){
        if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
            $texto = $_POST["texto"];
            $hoje = date("Y-m-d");
            
            if ($texto == ""){
                echo "<h3> Publicação vazia! </h3>";
            }else{
                $query = "INSERT INTO publicacao (usuario, texto, data) VALUES ('$login_cookie', '$texto', '$hoje')";
                $data = mysql_query($query) or die ();
                if ($data) {
                    header("Location ./");
                }else{
                    echo "Algo está errado! Tente outra vez mais tarde.";
                }
            }
        }else{
            $n = rand(0, 1000000);
            $img = $n.$_FILES["file"]["name"];
            
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/".$img);
            
            $texto = $_POST['texto'];
            $hoje = date("Y-m-d");
            
            if ($texto == ""){
                echo "<h3> Publicação vazia! </h3>";
            }else{
                $query = "INSERT INTO publicacao (usuario, texto, imagem, data) VALUES ('$login_cookie', '$texto', '$img', '$hoje')";
                $data = mysql_query($query) or die ();
                if ($data) {
                    header("Location ./");
                }else{
                    echo "Algo está errado! Tente outra vez mais tarde.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
    <head>
        <header>
            <style type="text/css">
                #publish{
                    width: 400px;
                    height: 210px;
                    display: block;
                    margin: auto;
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    background: #FFF;
                    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #A1A1A1;
                    margin-top: 30px;
                }
                #publish textarea{
                    width: 365px;
                    height: 150px;
                    display: block;
                    margin: auto;
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    padding-left: 5px;
                    padding-top: 5px;
                    border-width: 1px;
                    border-color: #A1A1A1;
                }
                #publish img{
                    margin-top: 0px;
                    margin-left: 10px;
                    width: 40px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
                #publish input[type="submit"]{
                    width: 70px;
                    height: 25px;
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    float: right;
                    margin-right: 15px;
                    border: none;
                    margin-top: 5px;
                    background: #4169E1;
                    color: #FFF;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
                #publish input[type="submit"]:hover{
                    background: #001F3F;
                }
                
                .pub{
                    width: 400px;
                    min-height: 70px;
                    max-height: 1000px;
                    display: block;
                    margin: auto;
                    border: none;
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    background-color: #FFF;
                    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #A1A1A1;
                    margin-top: 30px;
                }
                .pub a{
                    color: #666;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }
                .pub a:hover{
                    color: #111;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }
                .pub p{
                    margin-left: 10px;
                    content: #666;
                    padding-top: 10px;
                }
                .pub span{
                    display: block;
                    margin: auto;
                    width: 380px;
                    margin-top: 10px;
                }
                .pub img{
                    display: block;
                    margin: auto;
                    width: 100%;
                    margin-top: 10px;
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
                }
            </style>
        </header>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="publish">
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <br>
                <textarea placeholder="O que você está pensando nesse momento?" name="texto"></textarea>
                <label for="file-input">
                    <img src="img/imagegrey.png" title="Fazer upload de foto" />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Publicar" name="publish" />
                
                <input type="file" id="file-input" name="file" hidden />
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
            while ($pub = mysql_fetch_assoc($pubs)){
                $email = $pub['usuario'];
                $saberr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email='$email'");
                $saber = mysql_fetch_assoc($saberr);
                $nome = $saber['nome']." ".$saber['sobrenome'];
                $id = $pub['id'];
                
                if($pub['imagem']==""){
                    echo '<div class="pub" id="'.$id.'">
                            <p><a href="#">'.$nome.'</a> - '.$pub["data"].'</p>
                            <span>'.$pub['texto'].'</span><br /> </div>';
                }else{
                    echo '<div class="pub" id="'.$id.'">
                            <p><a href="#">'.$nome.'</a> - '.$pub["data"].'</p>
                            <span>'.$pub['texto'].'</span>'
                            . '<img src="upload/'.$pub["imagem"].'" /> </div>';
                }
            }
        ?>
        <br>
        <div id="footer"><p>&copy;CTRL-ALT-DEL - Direitos reservados.</p></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Duplicando publicações]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está fazendo o select no começo do código, antes de inserir o post novo, então o post novo não tem mesmo como aparecer, pois quando ele é inserido, você já pegou a listagem "velha".

A solução é tirar a linha marcada aqui:

```
<?php
    include("header.php");

    // TIRE ESSA LINHA DAQUI
    // $pubs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM publicacao ORDER BY id desc");

    if (isset($_POST['publish'])){
        if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
```

E passar para esta parte (veja o comment indicando o lugar):

```
                <input type="file" id="file-input" name="file" hidden />
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php

            // E PASSE PRA CÁ:
            $pubs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM publicacao ORDER BY id desc");

            while ($pub = mysql_fetch_assoc($pubs)){
                $email = $pub['usuario'];

                .... resto do código ...
```

Comment: O o que você falou funcionou aqui, só tem um porém agora: quando eu atualizo a página, ela reposta a última mensagem que eu postei só que, antes deu atualizar, vem aquela caixa de diálogo do navegador falando que vai reenviar o formulário. Seria possível evitar isso ou é algo do navegador mesmo?

Comment: Aí é um outro problema, é o fato de você tentar atualizar um POST. O ideal seria você separar os PHPs, um recebendo o post e gravando, e redirecionando o usuário para a página da listagem. Já tem uma postagem falando disso no site, se eu achar link posto aqui.

Comment: Não é uma pergunta com respostas, mas já tem umas dicas nos comentários: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160560/70

Comment: em resumo, você faz um form action="posta.php", e no posta.php você só grava no DB, mais nada, e ao final da um `header( 'Location: /listagem.php?'.uniqid() );` assim, se a pessoa der refresh, só vai dar na listagem. O `uniqid()` foi um exemplo, só para a página não ficar no cache e não atualizar.